# how to a create comment in sublime text editor?

Tags: sublimetext3

I am need a help to create **comment section** in **sublime text 3** for each ***controller*** and ***method***.
any idea for it please tell me.

other wise i want a created date and update date as like this `@param any parameter pass are mention here`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to comment out *or* uncomment the selected text *or* current line then:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
- Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Otherwise, use the menu: `Edit > Comment`

Block comment:

- Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>